# Framework for light client

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime, light-client, blockchain-frameworks

Is there any framework available by using it we can create light client for interoperable blockchains/substrate based blockchains

Answer (score 1):

Look at how [smoldot](https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot/) is constructed. It's specific to polkadot/parachain chains rather than a generic solution though. There's a lot of constraints if your targeting a light client that can run in the browser.